# Como descargar Excel generado por PHP SpreadSheet con Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, phpspreadsheet

necesito de su ayuda ya que estoy utilizando por primera ves `SpreadSheet` de PHP con el que genero un `Excel`, a este le envió parámetros mediante Ajax con los que pretendo se genere dicho `Excel`, el detalle esta al querer descargarlo en el `done` de la petición, el archivo se genera correctamente, he intentado con algunas respuestas que encontré generando un enlace `<a>` mediante JS pero genera un archivo corrupto, un **window.location** en el **succes** pero se pierden los parámetros que pretendo enviar.

No se que mas intentar, espero puedan ayudarme.

Petición Ajax con los intentos comentados:

```js
$.ajax({
  data: {
    mpios: checkValues
  },
  url: url,
  type: 'post',
  //responseType: "blob", // important
  beforesend: function() {

  },
}).always(function() {

}).done(function(res) {
  //INTENTO CON ENLACE 
  /*const urlr = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res]));
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = urlr;
  link.setAttribute("download", "departamento.xls");
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();*/

  //INTENTO CON EL REDIRECCIONAMIENTO
  //location.href = url;
  //alert(res);
}).fail(function() {
  alert('No se pudo relaizar la petición');
});
console.log(checkValues);
//console.log(e.target.id);
}
```

Código básico PHP que genera Excel:

```js
<?php
// Declaramos la librería
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\{Spreadsheet,IOFactory};
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
//CONEXION A BD
include '../BDOracle/connection.php';

if(isset($_POST['mpios'])){
    $mpiosArray = $_POST['mpios'];
    $mpios = implode(",", $mpiosArray);
    //echo 'PROCESO EXITOSO '.$mpios;

    
    //PROPIEDADES DE LA HOJA DE EXCEL
$spread = new Spreadsheet();
$spread
->getProperties()
->setCreator("Antonio Galicia")
->setLastModifiedBy('PHP')
->setTitle('Excel creado con PhpSpreadSheet')
->setSubject('Excel de prueba')
->setDescription('Excel generado como demostración')
->setKeywords('PHPSpreadsheet')
->setCategory('Categoría Excel');

$hoja1 = $spread->getActiveSheet();
$hoja1->setTitle("Inf. Estatal");

$fileName="Prueba_excel.xlsx";
# Crear un "escritor"
$writer = new Xlsx($spread);
# Le pasamos la ruta de guardado

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.urlencode($fileName).'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spread, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
exit();
}else{

}
```

Comment: hola, que dice la documentacion???

Answer (score 1):

El problema con tu código es que estás tratando de descargar el archivo Excel como un blob de JavaScript, pero esto no es compatible con todos los navegadores. La forma correcta de descargar un archivo Excel desde PHP es usar el encabezado Content-Disposition para indicar al navegador que debe descargar el archivo.

En tu caso, el código de la petición Ajax debería ser el siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
  data: {
    mpios: checkValues
  },
  url: url,
  type: 'post',
  beforesend: function() {

  },
}).always(function() {

}).done(function(res) {
  // Descarga el archivo Excel
  var blob = new Blob([res], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute("download", "departamento.xls");
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
}).fail(function() {
  alert('No se pudo relaizar la petición');
});
```

Este código creará un objeto Blob con el contenido del archivo Excel. Luego, usará el método createObjectURL() para crear una URL temporal para el archivo. Finalmente, creará un enlace  con la URL temporal y lo hará clicable.

El código de PHP también debe cambiarse para usar el encabezado Content-Disposition

```
// Declaramos la librería
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\{Spreadsheet,IOFactory};
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
//CONEXION A BD
include '../BDOracle/connection.php';

if(isset($_POST['mpios'])){
    $mpiosArray = $_POST['mpios'];
    $mpios = implode(",", $mpiosArray);
    //echo 'PROCESO EXITOSO '.$mpios;

    
    //PROPIEDADES DE LA HOJA DE EXCEL
$spread = new Spreadsheet();
$spread
->getProperties()
->setCreator("Antonio Galicia")
->setLastModifiedBy('PHP')
->setTitle('Excel creado con PhpSpreadSheet')
->setSubject('Excel de prueba')
->setDescription('Excel generado como demostración')
->setKeywords('PHPSpreadsheet')
->setCategory('Categoría Excel');

$hoja1 = $spread->getActiveSheet();
$hoja1->setTitle("Inf. Estatal");

$fileName="Prueba_excel.xlsx";
# Crear un "escritor"
$writer = new Xlsx($spread);
# Le pasamos la ruta de guardado

header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.urlencode($fileName).'"');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spread, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
exit();
}else{

}
```

Este código agregará el encabezado Content-Disposition con el valor attachment y el nombre del archivo Excel. Esto indicará al navegador que debe descargar el archivo

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu respuesta, aun agregando el **type** genera un archivo incompatible y lleno de símbolos, ya lo había generado así anteriormente con el código que tenia comentado en mis intentos, ademas la extensión debería ser **.xlsx** no **xls**, si la modifico me dice que el archivo esta dañado y no lo abre.

Comment: A mi se me ocurre general el archivo Excel en una dirección accesible por el usuario. Como parte de la respuesta AJAX se le proporciona el enlace de descarga al usuario y después de un periodo de tiempo alguna tarea que elimine el archivo. En fin, es.como generar el excel y presentarlo al usuario en su petición síncrona tradicional.